# Setup wiki to require edit approval on some pages, but not on others

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, library, versioning, wiki, content-approval

How can you setup the wiki to require edit approval on some pages, but not on others.

I know how to enable versioning and approval for the library, but is there a way that approval can be required only on certain pages?

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, this is an all or nothing setting. It is either content approval for everyone, or no one.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but thank you for confirming.

Comment: Couldn't you create a content type and have a workflow run on one but not the other?

Comment: Content approval is on the library, not the content type level, you could I suppose, but then once everyone knows you can use content type x to bypass content approval via automated workflow, no one would use content type y which would defeat the purpose.